# QML not registering property change from C++ property

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm displaying data in a `GridView` from a custom `QAbstractListItem` subclass (implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654426/2585092)). Adding and removing items works fine, QML is notified of the changes and transitions work fine.
Now I'm trying to set a property of an Item inside the model and have QML react on it. The problem is, the `onPropertyChanged` inside QML is not called.

Here is the property in C++:

```
// item.h
Q_PROPERTY(bool pToBeDeleted READ toBeDeleted NOTIFY toBeDeletedChanged)

// item.cpp
void Item::requestDelete()
{
    toBeDeleted_m = true;
    qDebug() << "emitting";
    emit toBeDeletedChanged();
}
```

This is what the GridView looks like:

```
// main.qml
GridView {
    id: grid

    // ...

    model: empty
    delegate: customComponent {
        toBeDeleted: pToBeDeleted
    }
    ListModel {
        id: empty
    }
}
```

When the program starts, `grid`'s `model` is set to my itemmodel.
And this is the QML type that does not see the changes:

```
// customComponentForm.ui.qml
Item {
    property bool toBeDeleted: false
}

// customComponent.qml
CustomComponentForm {
    onToBeDeletedChanged: {
        console.debug("change")
    }
}
```

Now when I call the method from inside the model like this:

```
this->items.at(i++)->requestDelete();
```

The output shows `emitting` but not `change`.

---

I have tried to include

```
emit dataChanged(createIndex(i, 0), createIndex(i, 0));
```

which did result in `onToBeDeletedChanged` to be called *sometimes*, but that also resulted in some wonky behaviour with the error

```
DelegateModel::item: index out range 3 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things went wrong here. First, because of the ++ at

```
this->items.at(i++)->requestDelete();
```

the `dataChanged` emit had the wrong index which resulted in wrong items being updated. Second of all,

```
emit dataChanged(createIndex(i, 0), createIndex(i, 0));
```

was missing the third argument, and since in another attempt I had tried inline defining of a Vector the wrong way, I didn't find this to be the problem right away. The right call here would have been

```
QVector<int> v;

v.append(Qt::UserRole + 7 + 1);
// pToBeDeleted being the 7th property, always check this with
// roleNames()[Qt::UserRole + i + 1]. It should say your property.

emit dataChanged(createIndex(i, 0), createIndex(i, 0), v);
```

My mistake.

But on another note, since the rolename index seems to be platform dependent and signaling the change from the model is somewhat of a dirty approach, a better solution (as suggested by [Kevin Krammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6842725/kevin-krammer)) would be to rewrite the itemmodel to only contain a single property, which is the `QObject` item. That way QML *is* notified of the changes item's properties have.

Comment: Since your model has QObject based items you could also just have a single role that returns the respective object and bind to the object's properties directly.
Then you don't ever have to emit dataChanged() unless the object at a specific index changes.
Also means you don't need comments like "check this with roleNames" since you then only have one, fixed, role

Comment: That sounds a lot better than what I'm doing. Do you have a source on how the change to my model would look like?

Comment: Basically you have one role and when that role is being asked for in `data()` you just return the QObject pointer for that index.
Lets assume your `roleNames()` maps that to the property name `object` then your QML can do `someDelegateProperty: model.object.propertyOfTheObject` (or without the `model.` if you prefer the less specific syntax)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!